# Let's open Package/packaging

Tags: grammar

Do you know babybel cheese that round and covered in red wax casing. Before you get to the wax part, you need to first peel the flimsy vinyl. What is this vinyl part called? Package or packaging?

Let's open the package/packaging.

Comment: I'd call it a "wrapper".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Where I live, Babybel is usually sold with three layers of ***packaging***:

- Each individual cheese has a ***wax coating.***
- Around the *wax coating* is a ***plastic wrapper.***  (Or just ***wrapper*** )
- Several cheeses in their *wax and plastic packaging* are then packed together in a ***mesh bag.***

When you are ready to eat one, you ***open*** the mesh bag, select a cheese, and ***remove*** the wrapper and the wax.  (Which you do by ***unwrapping*** the plastic, then ***peeling*** the wax off.)

Comment: Thank you, then would you use interchangably the wrapper and wrapping?

Comment: In general, I  do not use _wrapping_ as a noun.  Exception: Homemade coverings for gifts.   The term _wrapping paper_ refers to paper made specifically for wrapping things.  Sometimes I wrap birthday presents using _newspapers,_ or the _funny pages_ (newspaper comic strips.)  Sometimes I use _wrapping paper._  If I were encouraging someone to open a present I had wrapped with newspaper, I might say _"Take off the wrapping."_ ......

Comment: .....For a commercially made cheeseburger wrapped in paper, however, I would say _"take off the paper"_ or _"take off the wrapper."_  I can't claim that this is universal - it might be a personal idiosyncrasy.    You would certainly be understood either way. I would be interested to hear what other native speakers think about this nuance.  @TRomano?